# Change Username and Password of Tomcat JDBC Pool at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, hikaricp

with HikariCP it is possible to change Username and Password of the whole pool at runtime. You only have to set a poolName and set registerMbeans to true during the creation of the pool.
At runtime you could then use MXBeanProxy to change Username and password at runtime. It looks like this:

```
public void changeUser(HikariDataSource ds, String newUser, String newPassword) {
    HikariConfigMXBean configBean = ds.getHikariConfigMXBean();
    configBean.setUsername(user);
    configBean.setPassword(password);
            
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName poolName= new ObjectName("com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (" + dbKey + ")");
    HikariPoolMXBean poolProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mBeanServer, poolName, 
                                 HikariPoolMXBean.class);
    poolProxy.softEvictConnections();
}
```

But now I search some similar code for the Tomcat Connection Pool. Or another method to change username and password of Tomcat Connection Pool at runtime.

I hope somebody have an idea.

Comment: I would suggest using I/O to read out a properties file to then populate the changeUser method with the contents of this file. Make sure that the file is not in your classpath but somewhere where you can change it.

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Have you find a way to do this ?